# How to authenticate to MS Teams from a chatbot in a dedicated tenant with Microsoft Bot Framework SDK v4?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I have an authentication issue when sending requests to  MS Teams from a corporate environment (with a dedicated tenant). I don't know if this is a bug or if I misuse the SDK. I already saw [Teams samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples#teams-samples)  provided by Microsoft but all of these run on public Azure without dedicated tenant, and I suspect my issue is somewhat related to using a dedicated tenant (having a dedicated tenant, with either a bug in SDK, either a misconfiguration somewhere in my code or in the bot manifest).

The application I'm working on is very business specific, so I made a project to reproduce issue with minimal code in this github repository: [msteams-bot-auth-issue](https://github.com/eric-b/msteams-bot-auth-issue). **Using this sample project requires to have a Teams bot on a dedicated tenant** (I obviously cannot publish my corporate tenant details).

Basically, our application is splitted in two parts: one receives bot activities from MS Teams channel. Another processes them (first part forwards activities to the second one).

We correctly receive activities from MS Teams. **But we are unable to call an MS Teams API to get Teams members in conversation** (HTTP 401 with response message `{ "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request." }`).

Interestingly, if I use *Microsoft.Bot.Connector* v4.7.3 (version we actually use in our application), behavior is a bit different from Microsoft.Bot.Connector v4.15.0: in v4.7.3, no access token is requested before request to get conversation members; in v4.15.0, access token is successfully obtained, and put in request to conversation members request, but we still get an HTTP 401 response. Because we get HTTP 401 and not HTTP 403, I suppose access token is not recognized by MS Teams.

MS Teams response is always the same (HTTP 401 and error message), regardless an access token was included or not in request.

Access token request is composed of two requests:

- discovery (`GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/instance?api-version=1.1&authorization_endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX/oauth2/authorize` where `XXX` is our tenant name).
- client credentials request (`POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX/oauth2/authorize` where `XXX` is our tenant name).

Response contains access token, logs are showing "GetTokenAsync: Acquired token using ADAL in 876" (logs emitted by Bot Framework SDK).

Then actual conversation members request is sent with access token (with HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer ...`), and response is always HTTP 401.

When I decode the JWT in https://jwt.io, I see these fields (among others):

- aud: https://api.botframework.com
- iss: https://sts.windows.net/XXX/ (where XXX is our tenant name)
- idp: https://sts.windows.net/XXX/ (where XXX is our tenant name)
- appid: YYY (where Y is our *MicrosoftAppId*)

Interestingly, if a set scope parameter in `MicrosoftAppCredentials` class to `AuthenticationConstants.ToChannelFromBotOAuthScope`, nothing changes in the JWT. So maybe access rights are not correctly setup for our application.

Maybe this is an issue with our application manifest, but I think we followed samples for MS Teams bots. `permissions` field in our manifest is set to `[ "identity", "messageTeamMembers" ]`.

There are lots of resources about Bot Framework and MS Teams, but I did not found any meaningful documentation for this scenario.

This may be caused by a corporate proxy, but I don't think so (I cannot guarantee it).

I precise this is an app to app authentication, also sometimes described as "regular bot scenario" (no user authentication involved here).

Comment: My first guess is this is a proxy issue. If you are familiar with Fiddler, you can check the network trace to see at what point it is failing. Another option is to run the code (or a stripped down version of it) off of your corporate network and test if it is still blocked.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: Thanks @StevenKanberg, we are investigating on the corporate proxy. I will give feedback when I have more info. This is not something easy to investigate because it involves other teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @StevenKanberg comment, the issue is resolved and was related to a corporate proxy and to tenant restriction feature.

Here are my observations:

Even if we use a corporate MS Teams tenant, we must not authenticate to this tenant. I don't really understand why, but we have to authenticate to MS Teams directly. So when instantiating [`MicrosoftAppCredentials`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/4.15/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Authentication/MicrosoftAppCredentials.cs), argument `ChannelAuthTenant` must not be set (meaning default tenant "botframework.com" will be used). Curiously, authentication worked with our tenant id, but access token was not usable/recognized by MS Teams (error 401 returned by MS Teams). With default tenant, and without proper [tenant restrictions feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions) configuration, we could not authenticate in the first place (also with a more explicit error returned by MS Teams regarding tenant).

Comment: @chetansharma-msft: I marked the answer as accepted. Thanks.